# ListItems text not showing in Listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

The strangest thing happened to me in my asp.net application with a Listbox -- the ListItems are not showing their text. I know they are there because I can see them when I set breakpoints, and on top of that I am using almost the exact same code as I am on another page where they show up just fine. My listbox is on a panel that is called by a modal pop-up that looks like this:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="Button5"
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
DropShadow="True"
PopupControlID="Panel2" CancelControlID="Button5" OkControlID="Button5">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID = "Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="style3">
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="The following users are queued front of you. Select 'OK' to add your name  to the queue and 'Cancel' to cancel."></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox6" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:ListBox>
  <center>
    <asp:Button ID="reqOk" runat="server" Text="OK" onclick="reqOk_Clk" />
    <asp:Button ID="reqCncl" runat="server" Text="Cancel" onclick="reqCncl_Clk" />
  </center>
</asp:Panel>
```

The listbox (ListBox6) is populated like in the code behind page like this:

```
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings  
["something"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlcommand.Connection = sqlconn;
string cmd = "";
cmd = " SELECT devices.requestQueue, devices.invnumber FROM devices WHERE devices.invnumber='" + str + "'";
sqlcommand.CommandText = cmd;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcommand);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
object[] obj = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray;
sqlconn.Close();
hasRequest = true;
int i2 = 0;
if (!obj[0].Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
{
  string see = (string)obj[0];
  string[] words = see.Split(',');
  foreach (string word in words)
  {
    i2++;
    if (word.Contains(getname(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)))
    {
      showStuff = false;
      ListItem item = new ListItem(word);
      ListBox6.Items.Add(item);
      ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
      Label5.Text = "You have already requested " + (string)ViewState["inventory"] + ". Please press cancel and request a different device.";
      reqOk.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
      ListItem item = new ListItem(word);
      ListBox6.Items.Add(item);
    }
  }
}
/*foreach (object o in ListBox6.Items)
{
  Label4.Text += o.ToString() + " ";
}*/
if (showStuff == true)
{
  ListBox6.DataBind();
  if (obj[0].Equals(System.DBNull.Value) || (string)obj[0] == "")
    i2 = 0;
  Label5.Text = "The following " + i2 + " user(s) are queued in front of you for device " + str + ". Select 'OK' to add your name to the queue and 'Cancel' to cancel. Your name will not be added to the queue if you select 'Cancel'.";
ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
```

What makes this super frustrating is that when I uncomment this peice of code from above:

```
/*foreach (object o in ListBox6.Items)
{
  Label4.Text += o.ToString() + " ";
}*/
```

then Label 4 properly shows each of the items in the ListBox that I want my ListBox to be showing! So, I know the ListItems are being added to the ListBox correctly; I just cannot understand why they are not showing any text in the listbox. Any ideas?? Thanks

Comment: Another thing that doesn`t work:adding each name in words[] to an array list and using that as the datasource for the ListBox

Comment: Ok, I am going to assume this is just some weird bug that happened because to resolve this I just made a new modal popup extender and a new panel where everything was exactly the same as the old ones except for the name on the listbox and the name for the modal popup extender and now it works just fine...really weird but it works now. Will mark as answered after 4 more hours have passed since I have no reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

From your code, the problem is stemming `showStuff` being `true`.  You are adding items manually to your ListBox, then calling `ListBox.DataBind` on a non-databound list box, which will empty it's contents (since `AppendDataBoundItems` is not set to `true`).  Either set the `DataSource`, `DataValueField`, and `DataTextField`, or stop databinding and your ListBox should function as expected.

Comment: I commented out that line and it still didn`t fix the problem. I`m wondering if there is some visibility I need to set somewhere? When I set a breakpoint I can see that I have the correct ListItems in my ListBox, and that those ListItems have the correct text and value; I am just stumped as to why they have the correct text but it doesn`t show in my ListBox

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am going to assume this is just some weird bug that happened.  To resolve this I just made a new modal popup extender, a new panel and changed the name on the listbox and the modal popup extender. Now it works just fine... Really weird but it works now.